# using ApexChart for rails7 raising error Uncaught ReferenceError: ApexCharts is not defined

Tags: apexcharts, rails7

I'm new one in rails and trying to add Apexchart js to my project in rails7.

So i did

```js
document.addEventListener('turbo:load', function(){

  var options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'sales',
      data: [30,40,35,50,49,60,70,91,125]
    }],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]
    }
  }

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('.user-apex-chart'), options);

  if (chart) {
    chart.render();
  }


})
```

before I run
npm install apexcharts --save

I have Esbuild and turbo on

and add to application.js this:

```
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
```

in package.json it has apex

```
"dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.38",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "tom-select": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

no erorrs when I started the server..
but seems it doesn't see Apex.

What I did wrong?

the test code following below is working:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused because your application.js script tag has `defer="defer"` and the library by default renders script tags that expect `ApexCharts` to exist.

[Explanation of defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

The library supports passing `defer: true` to the options argument and then it will wrap create chart code inside an event listener.

```
 <%= line_chart series, {defer: true} %>
```

I don't know if the event listener will work with turbo yet though.

Comment: Thank you! Would you know how to show a total value in the tooltip? I can't seem to get the following to run using functionable-json:

<%= area_chart(series, chart_id: 'area-chart-with-gradient', **options, xaxis: xaxis, yaxis: yaxis, defer:true, tooltip: {
  y: {
    formatter: function(value, opts) {

      const sum = opts.series.reduce((a, b) => a + b.data.reduce((innerSum, number) => innerSum + number, 0), 0);
      return '$' + parseFloat(sum).toLocaleString()
    }
  }
}
) %>